# Solving multi-armed bandit problems with continuous action space

Tags: reinforcement-learning, multi-armed-bandits

My problem has a single state and an infinite amount of actions on a certain interval (0,1). After quite some time of googling I found a few paper about an algorithm called zooming algorithm which can solve problems with a continous action space. However my implementation is bad at exploiting. Therefore I'm thinking about adding an epsilon-greedy kind of behavior.

Is it reasonable to combine different methods?

Do you know other approaches to my problem?